# Web API Restful service ReadAsAsync<type> not returning lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to return lists of objects inside of a class, however when I try to read the result into the container class it nulls out the lists.  I am pretty new to Web API so I don't know if this is by design or if I am doing something wrong.  If I read the response content into a string the lists are there.  The first image shows that the lists are intact and the second shows that they are no longer available.  Any direction would be appreciated!  [image: response created]
[image: null values when readasasync<t>]

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string url = Url(String.Format("{0}", id));
                SetupClient(client, url);

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {


                    shipment = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ShipmentViewModel>().Result;

                }
```

**Edit for adding ShipmentViewModel source**

```
public class ShipmentViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public String ShipmentName { get; set; }

    public String Description { get; set; }

    public String Comments { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for UI display purposes only
    /// </summary>

    public int NumberOrdersScanned { get; set; }
    public int NumberOrdersTotal { get; set; }

    public int NumberParcelsScanned { get; set; }
    public int NumberParcelsTotal { get; set; }

    public List<ShipmentEntity> ShipmentEntities { get; set; }

    public ShipmentEntity ShipmentEntity { get; set; }
    public Guid ValidationTypeId { get; set; }
    //        public string ValidationType { get; set; }
    public ValidationType ValidationType { get; set; }
    public List<ValidationType> ValidationTypes { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Used for UI display purposes only
    /// </summary>
    public List<ShipmentStatus> ShipmentStatuses { get; set; }

    public ShipmentStatus ShipmentStatus { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for UI display purposes only
    /// </summary>
    public List<ShipmentDestinationCountry> DestinationCountries { get; set; }

    public ShipmentDestinationCountry DestinationCountry { get; set; }

    private List<ShipmentTrackingNumber> _TrackingNumbers;
    public List<ShipmentTrackingNumber> TrackingNumbers
    {
        get
        {
            return _TrackingNumbers ?? (_TrackingNumbers = new List<ShipmentTrackingNumber>());
        }
        set
        {
            _TrackingNumbers = value;
        }
    }

    public bool RequiresValidation { get; set; }
    private List<ShipmentValidationViewModel> _Validations { get; set; }

    public List<ShipmentValidationViewModel> Validations
    {
        get
        {
            return _Validations ?? (_Validations = new List<ShipmentValidationViewModel>());
        }
        set
        {
            _Validations = value;
        }
    }

    public Guid EdiShipmentInfoId { get; set; }
    public EdiShipmentInfoViewModel EdiShipmentInfo { get; set; }

    public ShipmentEvents Events { get; set; }
}
```

**Here is the EdiShipmentInfoViewModel**

```
 public class EdiShipmentInfoViewModel
{
    //        private string _packagingCode;
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ShipmentId { get; set; }
    public Guid WarehouseId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel Warehouse { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ShippingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public string EquipmentNumber { get; set; }

    public string ShippingWeight { get; set; }

    public string PackagingCode { get; set; }

    public string CarrierCommonName { get; set; }
    public Guid ScacCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel ScacCode { get; set; }
    public Guid PackagingFormId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel PackagingForm { get; set; }
    public Guid PackagingMaterialId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel PackagingMaterial { get; set; }

    public string MasterBillLading { get; set; }
    public string BillLading { get; set; }
    public string LadingDescription { get; set; }
    public string FobShippingPoint { get; set; }
    public string FobDestination { get; set; }
    public Guid TransPayMethodId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel TransPayMethod { get; set; }
    public Guid TransTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel TransType { get; set; }
    public Guid ServiceLevelCodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel ServiceLevelCode { get; set; }
    public Guid UnitOfMeasureId { get; set; }
    public virtual InternalLookupModel UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }


    private List<InternalLookupModel> _WarehouseList;
    public List<InternalLookupModel> WarehouseList
    {
        get { return _WarehouseList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._WarehouseList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _ScacCodeList;

    public List<InternalLookupModel> ScacCodeList
    {
        get { return _ScacCodeList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._ScacCodeList = value; }
    }
    private List<InternalLookupModel> _PackagingFormList;
    public List<InternalLookupModel> PackagingFormList
    {
        get { return _PackagingFormList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._PackagingFormList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _PackagingMaterialList;
    public List<InternalLookupModel> PackagingMaterialList
    {
        get { return _PackagingMaterialList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._PackagingMaterialList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _TransPayMethodList;
    public List<InternalLookupModel> TransPayMethodList
    {
        get { return _TransPayMethodList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._TransPayMethodList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _TransTypeList;
    public List<InternalLookupModel> TransTypeList
    {
        get { return _TransTypeList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._TransTypeList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _ServiceLevelCodeList;

    public List<InternalLookupModel> ServiceLevelCodeList
    {
        get { return _ServiceLevelCodeList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._ServiceLevelCodeList = value; }
    }

    private List<InternalLookupModel> _UnitOfMeasureList;

    public List<InternalLookupModel> UnitOfMeasureList
    {
        get { return _UnitOfMeasureList ?? new List<InternalLookupModel>(); }
        set { this._UnitOfMeasureList = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the source code for `ShipmentViewModel`. I'm not an expert in this area, but I suspect the type you are using for the list may not be compatible with whatever is deserializing the object into your type.

Comment: @Brian Ball : I have added in the shipmentviewmodel source as requested

Comment: You *should* be hitting deadlock on `.Result`. Check out threads view when problem happens. Feel free to find corresponding duplicate with searches like "C# ASP.Net wait async deadlock" if it is the case.

Comment: I am not seeing any deadlocks it is just not populating the lists of the object that I am trying to fill.  The lists are being passed back from the service call but when using `.ReadAsAsync<t>` it does not bring those lists into the object

Comment: Again, no expert, which is why I'm posting here and not an answer. I would try to simplify your property (just make them basic getter/setters, no special logic), and change from `List<T>` to either `IEnumerable<T>` or `T[]` where `T` is the appropriate type. Depending on what deserializer is used by the framework, it may not have logic to deal with the `List<T>` type.

Comment: @BrianBall I tried switching the type to an `IEnumerable<T>` but same results.. I suppose I will just have to make a separate API call for each list I suppose but it seems like there would be a better way.  Thanks for the sugguestion though.

Comment: What happens when you call the WebAPI method from directly your browser? Do you see the serialized collection there (in JSON or XML)?

Comment: @howcheng When using SoapUI and sending the request I get the JSON response with the lists as expected

Comment: Don't give up. Making a separate call for each collection will slow your application down dramatically. I did a very quick and simple test and it works fine. I had it working with arrays, IEnumerables and Lists. My recommendation to you is to simplify your code as much as possible. Have an object with only one property that is a collection and see if you can get that to work. If that works, then add some complexity and see if it still works. Do that until it breaks, then you'll at least have a better idea of what exactly is causing the problem.

Comment: @BrianBall I actually just started doing that myself, I didn't write the base of this code I was just given the task to add some functions to it so I'm still learning how it all goes together and why.  I'll report back on what I find.  Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think @BrianBall is correct. Rewrite your class so that your list properties are simple getters/setters and initialize the lists in your constructor.

```
public class ShipmentViewModel
{
  public ShipmentViewModel()
  {
    TrackingNumbers = new List<ShipmentTrackingNumber>();
  }

  public List<ShipmentTrackingNumber> TrackingNumbers { get; set; }
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to initialize any collections if you are deserializing an object. My experience with deserializers is that they simply create the collection from scratch and call the setter on the property, they don't call the getter to get an instance and add items from there (since not all IEnumerables support adding items).

Comment: Thank you everyone I have it working now, I moved the list to be instantiated in the constructor and that seems to have done it.  Thanks again to everyone for helping me out on this one!